# Adding views dynamiclly into table row

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablelayout

I have table layout which has several rows ,each row contains a textView n an editText. I have a blank row which I want to populate with a textView n an editText dynamically. I added a textView(hips) but its not showing as the others. See below, in the 3rd row the textView is shown trasnparent. I want to add the same textView n an editText as above rows dynamically.

[image]

```
 TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tblHips);
     TextView txt=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
     txt.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
     txt.setId(R.id.txtHipId);
     txt.setText("Hips");
     row.addView(txt);
```

I have added code for only rows from waist downwards-

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Waist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tblHips"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rdMs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Imperial" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Metric" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Can we see the layout file you have or at least the part with one of the rows from the image?

Comment: Adding the `TextView` with this `LayoutParams` makes a difference? `row.addView(txt, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: No its NOT making any difference. I m really amazed why the textView is looking transparent?....1 more thing the table row layout is already set in layout file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `TextView` looks transparent is because the alpha for the text isn't set to 255. `txt.setAlpha(255);` will fix that issue.

If your just going to have one hidden field, the best way to approach the problem is put all the views in xml, and 'hide' the hidden views with `android:visibility="gone"`. Then in your code you can toggle between `View.GONE` `View.VISIBLE` (you want to use gone, because it removes the view from the layout).

If you really need to add the views during runtime, your going to need to specify every little detail like text size (and change it with different dpi), text color/alpha, etc. Which quickly becomes a nightmare to support. In this case you should make a separate layout .xml file and use a layout inflater to generate the views.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.hips, container, false);
//where 'container' is the containing TableView & 'this' is an activity
```

Comment: I used xml layout for the row content and add this like - View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layouthips, null);row.addView(v); which is working well. But the View.GONE View.VISIBLE method seems nice.

Comment: Great! If your not doing any dynamic (multiple new rows generated by the user); its probably going to be easier to define all the rows in one xml. Then you can hide/show with visibility.